# ASP.Net download file

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have to download a file and use a progress bar to track the download progress, this in ASP.Net Web Forms.

So far I managed to download the file, but not to track the download progress. How can I do?

```
        try
        {
            string filePath = MapPath(path);
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                //Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
                Response.Flush();
                Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle error
        }
```

Comment: This is an http protocol problem... typically you have to settle for letting the browser do it.

Comment: Is there another way which would let me handle the progress?